# Select table.* as prefix_[table.columname], is that possible? (or easy?)

Tags: sql, sql-server

`MainTable` and `SubTable` have a lot of columns.

```
SELECT Sub.*, Main.* FROM 
(
SELECT * FROM [SubTable]
) Sub
LEFT OUTER JOIN [MainTable] main
ON Sub.MainID = Main.ID
```

This query returns every column of every table.

Some of the columns in `SubTable` have the same name as some in the `MainTable` f.e. `created` or `modified` and lots of other ones.

Is there a way in SQL Server to do something like (without listing every column):

```
Select Sub.* as sub_[subcolumnname], Main.* as main_[columnname]
```

its hard for me finding a term for what I want, which makes it nearly impossible to google it.

Any advice is welcome, thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this kind of thing only with dynamic sql: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/generate-dynamic-sql-statements-in-sql-server/306